# How to make the text inside the button for the forum action bigger

Tags: html, css

```html
<form action="https://www.kroger.com/account/communityrewards/" >
     <input type="submit" value="Go to Krogers" style="height: 50px; width: 150px;" />
    </form>
```

I'm just curious of how to make the forum action text bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting **[`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)** on `input` (or [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance) it down from `form`):

```css
input {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.kroger.com/account/communityrewards/">
  <input type="submit" value="Go to Krogers" style="height: 50px; width: 150px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what I was doing wrong. I didn't need to make a class to do this.

Comment: You don't; the CSS selector `input` targets the HTML **tag** `input` (`<input>`). If you want to be more specific and use a class, you would use something like `<input class="form-input">` and a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) of `.form-input`, though that is likely unnecessary, and would only be needed if you were worried about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use rem units which is relative to only the root element

```css
input {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.kroger.com/account/communityrewards/">
  <input type="submit" value="Go to Krogers" style="height: 50px; width: 150px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just showing all the ways you can adjust your text size

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking into them now to understand them and how they differ.